# Vert.x websocket client - 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, websocket, vert.x, java-websocket, vertx-httpclient

*How can I connect [Cex.IO websocket API](https://cex.io/websocket-api) from my Java verticles?*

The problem is that Vert.x doesn't provide me with a way to connect only with WsURI [as Node.JS does](https://github.com/Erowlin/cex-websocket/blob/master/index.js). I have to specify port and host and get HTTP 400 Bad Request exception.

With Node.js you do:

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
var client = new WebSocketClient();
client.connect("wss://ws.cex.io/ws/");
```

With Vert.x you have to do

```
int host = 443; // That's defaults
String host = "cex.io"; // Am I right by specifying this host?
HttpClient client = Vertx.vertx().createHttpClient();
client.websocket(port, host, "wss://ws.cex.io/ws/", ws -> { ...});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [HttpClient#websocket](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpClient.html#websocket-int-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-io.vertx.core.Handler-) method takes a relative URI as third parameter.

You should be able to connect like this:

```
client = vertx.createHttpClient(new HttpClientOptions()
  .setDefaultHost("ws.cex.io")
  .setDefaultPort(443)
  .setSsl(true));

client.websocket("/ws", ws -> {
  // Work with the websocket
});
```

Comment: Wow great answer, thanks! Vert.x documentation is not particularly clean on client side WSS, and the examples also skip this little trick required for WSS.

Comment: @GeeBee the doc is on GitHub. How about a PR?